# error on pressing back button on webview app android

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an android app that uses `WebView`. I am getting an error when the back button is pressed called error cache miss. I have the internet permission and I have also disabled cache, but still I am getting the same error.

```
public class MyChooserHtmlCheck extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
private String TAG;
WebView web;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
String post_detail, post_url;

public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
private boolean isChatLoad = false;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
            if (uploadMessage == null)
                return;
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
            uploadMessage = null;
        }
    } else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
        // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
        // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MyChooserHtmlCheck.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    } else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TAG = MyChooserHtmlCheck.this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    createIds();
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Please wait Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    clearCookies(MyChooserHtmlCheck.this);

    getDetail();


}


private void createIds() {
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.MyTheme);
    progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

}

private void getDetail() {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String ChatCall = "";
    if (intent.hasExtra("NotificationMessage")) {
        post_detail = "";
        ChatCall = intent.getStringExtra("chatMessage");
        isChatLoad = true;
        post_detail = intent.getStringExtra(Itag.post_login);
        post_url = intent.getStringExtra(Itag.post_login_url);
    } else {
        post_detail = intent.getStringExtra(Itag.post_login);
        post_url = intent.getStringExtra(Itag.post_login_url);
    }
    LoadwebView(post_detail, post_url);

}

// Load View
private void LoadwebView(String post_detail, String post_Url) {
    web = new WebView(this);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    //    web.loadUrl("http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/199/index.html");
    WebViewClient wb = new WebViewClient();

    WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Silver LifeStyle");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    web.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();

            Log.e(TAG,  hr.getExtra() + "Type ==  " + hr.getType());

            return false;
        }
    });

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e("url", "url : " + url);
            if (!(MyChooserHtmlCheck.this).isFinishing()) {
                if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.setTitle("Silver LifeStyle");
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");

                    progressDialog.show();
                }

            }


         //   if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("https://consignchain.net/optisoft/logout.php")) {
            if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("https://titankart.com/optisoft/logout.php")) {

                SavedData.saveLogin(false);
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                finish();
                return true;
            } else if (url != null && url.startsWith("https://") && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("https://titankart.com/optisoft/logout.php")) {
                Log.e("Prince New", "" + url);
                SavedData.saveLogin(true);
                web.loadUrl(url);


                return true;
            } else {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                SavedData.saveLogin(false);
                //1
                Intent i = new Intent(MyChooserHtmlCheck.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

                return false;
            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e("on Finish", "Url : " + url);
            if (isChatLoad) {
                web.loadUrl("https://titankart.com/optisoft/inbox.php?");
                isChatLoad = false;
            }

            if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("https://titankart.com/api.php")) {
                Toast.makeText(MyChooserHtmlCheck.this, "Invalid Credential ....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SavedData.saveLogin(false);
                //2
                Intent i = new Intent(MyChooserHtmlCheck.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("https://titankart.com/api.php")) {
                Toast.makeText(MyChooserHtmlCheck.this, "Invalid Credential ....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SavedData.saveLogin(false);
                //3
                Intent i = new Intent(MyChooserHtmlCheck.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("https://titankart.com/index8.php")) {
                Toast.makeText(MyChooserHtmlCheck.this, "Invalid Credential ....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SavedData.saveLogin(false);
                //4
                Intent i = new Intent(MyChooserHtmlCheck.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    web.postUrl(post_Url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(this.post_detail, "base64"));

    setChrome();

}


// Manage Dialog and Attachment
private void setChrome() {

    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        //The undocumented magic method override
        //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here
        // For Android 3.0+
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }


        // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (uploadMessage != null) {
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                uploadMessage = null;
            }

            uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                uploadMessage = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        //For Android 4.1 only
        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    });
    setContentView(web);
}

public static void clearCookies(Context context) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        Log.e("clear cache", "Using clearCookies code for API >=" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
    } else {
        Log.e("clear cache", "Using clearCookies code for API <" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1));
        CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
        cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
        cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
        cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
        cookieSyncMngr.sync();
    }
}

//flipscreen not loading again
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


}

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Below is the manifest file where the internet permission is active.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="business.supply.yourguide.consignchain.comstock.Titankart">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />


<application
    android:name="business.supply.yourguide.consignchain.comstock.Titankart.app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeFullscreen">
    <activity android:name="business.supply.yourguide.consignchain.comstock.Titankart.Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="business.supply.yourguide.consignchain.comstock.Titankart.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <!--  <activity
          android:name="business.supply.yourguide.consignchain.comstock.consignchain.MainActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"></activity>
  -->
    <activity
        android:name="business.supply.yourguide.consignchain.comstock.Titankart.RegisterActvity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="business.supply.yourguide.consignchain.comstock.Titankart.VerificationDetail"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="business.supply.yourguide.consignchain.comstock.Titankart.MyChooserWeb"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"></activity>
    <!--Notification Services-->

    <service android:name="business.supply.yourguide.consignchain.comstock.Titankart.Firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="business.supply.yourguide.consignchain.comstock.Titankart.Firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <receiver
        android:name="business.supply.yourguide.consignchain.comstock.Titankart.Firebase.FirebaseDataReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/icon" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!--End zNotification Services-->


</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: This happens only when I am not logged in to the webview. When I am logged in I do not face this issue.

Comment: Hi, can anyone help on this soon.